# How to fix this css to conform to all browsers?

Tags: css

My [application](http://ting-1.appspot.com/) built with Google App Engine has this page that displays [search results](http://ting-1.appspot.com/rt?rt=google%20app%20engine).

In my laptop the design and font size look fine (I use Chrome); but in the bigger display on a desktop with IE, the title looks huge and the text under the title is grayed out (it shouldn’t be). Below is the css that I am using. I appreciate your help regarding the design and any problems you see with it. Thanks.

css for the body (text under the title):

```
body { font-size: small; font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif; }
```

css for the title:

```
#large {color: #0066CC; font-size: large; }
```

css for “comment”

```
#small {color: #808080; font-size: x-small; }
```

**EDIT**

In IE I also noticed that the text under the title is grayed out. What is the reason for that? This is the code:

```
        self.response.out.write("""<p>
        <a href="%s"><span id=large>%s</span></a> 
        <a href="/comment?main_id=%s"><span id="small">comments</span></a><br />  
        %s 
        </p>
        """ %           
        (item.url, item.title, main_id, 
        item.pitch))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using percentages or pixel values instead of keywords for the font-size. Different browsers interpret those keywords differently, which is why you're seeing the discrepancy.

Comment: Setting a percentage size for `body` should do.

Comment: I added an edit to my question about the text that is grayed out. Any help with that? Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel, can I see the page with the grayed out symptom? Thanks.

Comment: Search result pages like this one `http://ting-1.appspot.com/rt?rt=google%20app%20engine` appear ok on my laptop using Chrome; but on a desktop at work using IE I see the text under the title gray. Thanks.

Comment: @Zeynel, it looks like you're using the "small" id to mark text as gray. IDs should be unique. If you want to use "small" in multiple places, make it a class, not an id. 

In CSS, refer to ".small" instead of "#small" to reference the class instead of the ID.

Answer (score 2):

Not that this is the direct cause of the problem, but the first thing I notice is that you're using IDs instead of classes for styling multiple elements.

So this:

```
<span id="small">
```

should be:

```
<span class="small">
```

And your `#small` selector should be `.small`. Likewise goes for `large`.

Zach Rattner should have identified the real problem though.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Ok I will change that to class. Can this be the reason why the text under the title looks grayed out in IE?

Comment: @Zeynel: I'm not sure about that.